# Auto Update Data on Page when Args are changed in URL - Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, url, arguments

I have a flask app that extract 3 values from url in form of arguments like - ticker , start date , end date

The issue that i face is when i first hit the url it returns me data correctly although when i try it next time while changing the values of arguments it doesn't work

Standard form of URL- `127.0.0.1:5000/api?ticker=IEX&start=25-04-2022&end=25-05-2022`

Although when i lets say change the start value from 25-04-2022 to 25-03-2022 arguments the code returns the same value as it did for the first one.

Here's my code

```
import requests
from datetime import date 
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask import request

config = {
    "CACHE_TYPE": "SimpleCache",  # Flask-Caching related configs
    "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": 0,
}

app = Flask(__name__)
# tell Flask to use the above defined config
app.config.from_mapping(config)
cache = Cache(app)

@app.route("/api")
@cache.cached(timeout=0)
def index():
    # https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=IEX&series=[%22EQ%22]&from=25-04-2022&to=25-05-2022
    ticker = request.args.get( 'ticker', None)
    start = request.args.get( 'start', None) #25-04-2022
    end = request.args.get( 'end', None) #25-05-2022
    s = requests.Session()
    headers =   {'Host':'www.nseindia.com', 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0','Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br','DNT':'1', 'Connection':'keep-alive', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1','Pragma':'no-cache','Cache-Control':'no-cache',  }
    url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/'
    step = s.get(url,headers=headers)
    api_url = f"https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol={ticker}&series=[%22EQ%22]&from={start}&to={end}"
    result = s.get(api_url,headers=headers).json()
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're caching with timeout as 0, so the cache is set for infinite time

```
@cache.cached(timeout=0)
```

try commenting out or removing the following lines

```
cache = Cache(app)
@cache.cached(timeout=0)
```